# Pump well and hot water heater

Tags: water, heater, pump, well, leaking

[image]I have a few questions honestly. I work away on towboats so I'm away from home a lot when things go bad, my fiance contacted me to let me know the hot water heater is leaking in the house and has been for awhile and we didn't notice it. But then she goes out by the pump shed and there are two leaks out there. 1 is coming from the gauge; which I would assume is the pressure relief valve; it has happened quite a bit in the last 10 years there have been at least 8 leaks with it. The other leak is coming from something idk what it's called but looks like a valve stem that happens to be under the s

Comment: Yes, what is the question?

Comment: What is the piece called that the water is shooting from in the picture and what could cause the 3 leaks that simultaneously happened?

Comment: That looks like a valve stem, so I'm assuming this is a pressure tank. It could be a bad valve stem. Given that you didn't notice the hot water leak for a while, any chance that you didn't notice at least one of the other leaks as well? If this is genuinely a cluster of failures, I'd say something ran the pressure up too high (bad pressure switch on the pump?) but that's at best a guess.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking it's a bad pressure switch and it blew all three leaks at once, I noticed my pressure in the bathroom farthest away lost pressure like 2 weeks ago but I never seen the leaks then, and it's low pressure on the cold and hot water. But I thought the same with the pressure. I know that I've changed that pressure relief valve like 8 times in 10 years, so it is gradually getting worse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I assume this pressure tank does not have a bladder/diaphragm in it.  Have you ever added air to the tank?  Pressure valves should last longer than a year unless the tank is water logged(no air in the tank) and the switch is off/on all the time when using water, which will burn out the contacts.  The valve stem is how you add air to the tank.

Comment: I have written my question in the comments. I asked what the piece was that was leaking in the picture and what would cause three leaks to simultaneously happen, 2 on the well and 1 in the hot water heater.

Comment: The piece is the valve stem, almost the same as on a tire.  It is probably loose(the centre comes out) or needs replacement.

Comment: I don't think it has a diaphragm on it, I've never personally added air to it. I didn't know you was supposed to. I thought u was supposed to bleed air out honestly. Lol

Comment: I thought that's what It looks like was a valve stem. And If I remember correctly it was capped off.

Answer (score 0):

Replace/repair the stem.

Turn off the power to the tank/pump.  Drain the tank at least half way, you need a faucet open to drain and let air into the tank.

Close the faucet and fill/turn the power back on to the tank and you should be good for a few months.  Repeat as needed.

Will get some air out of the faucets for a few minutes till the pipes are bled/full of water again.

If you keep doing this, you should find the pressure switch lasting for years.

The hot water tank will need replacement.  No repair for leaking hot water tanks that is worth doing.